# Is it possible to discard chests in clash royale?

Tags: clash-royale

Well I was wondering whether it was possible to discard of silver chest which are not worth the time, and stack up gold chest instead

Comment: Discard function would be nice to have.

Comment: They don't want players to become very high by just playing very much. (This would be the case as you could play as long as you receive a super magic chest.) Reason: The game is funded by gem purchase and the earnings would probably decrease with introducing such a function. Compromiss: Since the new update you get gold even if you have all chest slots (but also with a cap per day which is 20 times)

Answer (score 13):

No.

The only way to get rid of a chest is to open it.
[Source.](https://supercell.helpshift.com/a/clash-royale/?s=cards-chests&f=can-i-remove-a-chest-manually&p=web)